# How come Donyatsu can stand in the rain?

Tags: donyatsu

In chapter 3, Donyatsu gets attacked by the Machumaro, and they take a bit from his back:

[image: Ouch, that's gotta hurt!]
With this, we know that (at least) a superficial layer of his body is composed of some kind of pastry, which is even edible.

We also know that Donyatsu needs to eat, which means he somehow has a digestive system.

In chapter 13, however, Donyatsu is seen standing in the rain:

[image: Lonely Donyatsu in the rain...]

**How can he stand in the rain and not melt (he has a sugar coating) or get soaked (since he's made of pastry)?**

Furthermore, how exactly does his body (and of the bodies of the rest of his gang) really work, physiologically?

Comment: The same way [nyan cat](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4) flies through space and poops rainbows (in space).